# How to debug Bugzilla extension that doesn't appear to run?

Tags: perl, debugging, bugzilla

I need some help getting a bugzilla extension off the ground.

I want to hook into [`bug_format_comment`](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/3.6/en/html/api/Bugzilla/Hook.html#bug_format_comment) (FWIW: to change some plain text automatically added as a comment when I commit to SVN to links to the respective SCM commit.)

Right now, nothing seems to happen when I manually add a comment to a bug.

Is there anything special I need to do to make the extension run, besides putting it in the /extensions/my-ext-name/ dir ?
How can I test if the extension is called at all?

I use an old version of Bugzilla (3.2.x). Is that hook even supported? (I can't find that info in the documentation).

Here's my complete `Extension.pm` file (I have no experience in Perl. I took the example of the hook from the example extension and ran from there)

```
package Bugzilla::Extension::Websvn-scmbug-autolink;
use strict;
use base qw(Bugzilla::Extension);
# This code for this is in ./extensions/Websvn-scmbug-autolink/lib/Util.pm
use Bugzilla::Extension::Websvn-scmbug-autolink::Util;
use URI::Escape;

our $VERSION = '0.01';

# See the documentation of Bugzilla::Hook ("perldoc Bugzilla::Hook" 
# in the bugzilla directory) for a list of all available hooks.
sub install_update_db {
    my ($self, $args) = @_;

}

sub bug_format_comment {
    my ($self, $args) = @_;


    my $regexes = $args->{'regexes'};
    # push(@$regexes, { match => qr/\bfoo\b/, replace => 'bar' });


# 6665 --> 6666
# CTUFramework:trunk/CTUCsharpRuntime/CtuFramework/text1-renamed.txt
    #my $bar_match = qr/\b(bar)\b/;
    my $bar_match = qr/(?:^|\r|\n)(\d+|NONE) (--&gt;) (\d+|NONE)[ \r\n\t]+([^:]+):(.*?)[\r\n]/s; #/s - treat as single line
    push(@$regexes, { match => $bar_match, replace => \&_replace_bar });
    my $scm_match2 = qr/(?:^|\r|\n)(\d+|NONE) (-->) (\d+|NONE)[ \r\n\t]+([^:]+):(.*?)[\r\n]/s; #/s - treat as single line
    push(@$regexes, { match => $scm_match2, replace => \&_replace_bar });
}

# Used by bug_format_comment--see its code for an explanation.
sub _replace_bar {
    my $args = shift;

    my $scmFromVer = $args->{matches}->[0]; 
    my $scmToVer = $args->{matches}->[1];
    my $scmArrow = $args->{matches}->[2];
    my $scmProject = $args->{matches}->[3];
    my $scmFile = $args->{matches}->[4];
    # Remember, you have to HTML-escape any data that you are returning!
    my $websvnRoot = "http://devlinux/websvn";
    my $websvnRepo = uri_escape($scmProject); #maybe do a mapping
    my $websvnFilePath = uri_escape("/".$scmFile);

    my $fromRevUrl = sprintf("%s/revision.php?repname=%s&rev=%s", 
        $websvnRoot, $websvnRepo, $scmFromVer);
    my $toRevUrl =   sprintf("%s/revision.php?repname=%s&rev=%s", 
        $websvnRoot, $websvnRepo, $scmToVer);
    my $diffUrl =    sprintf("%s/diff.php?repname=%s&path=%s&rev=%s", 
        $websvnRoot, $websvnRepo, $websvnFilePath, $scmToVer);
    my $fileUrl =    sprintf("%s/filedetails.php?repname=%s&path=%s&rev=%s", 
        $websvnRoot, $websvnRepo, $websvnFilePath, $scmToVer);

    # TODO no link for 'NONE'
    my $fromRevLink = sprintf(qq{<a href="%s">%s</a>}, $fromRevUrl, $scmFromVer);
    my $toRevLink =   sprintf(qq{<a href="%s">%s</a>}, $toRevUrl, $scmToVer);
    my $diffLink =    sprintf(qq{<a href="%s">%s</a>}, $diffUrl, $scmArrow);
    my $fileLink =    sprintf(qq{<a href="%s">%s</a>}, $fileUrl, $scmFilePath);
    # $match = html_quote($match);
    return "$fromRevLink $diffLink $toRevLink:$fileLink";
};
__PACKAGE__->NAME;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched the Bugzilla sources, and found that the hook is simply not supported in version 3.2.x. The hook was introduced in Bugzilla 3.6: http://bzr.mozilla.org/bugzilla/3.6/revision/6762

PS. I hacked the regex replaces right in the template script for comments. Hacky, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

As written, your extension won't even load: dashes are not valid in Perl package names.

Change the name from `Websvn-scmbug-autolink` to `Websvn_scmbug_autolink`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Like I said, Perl is a foreign language to me :)